# Extract term from computation

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers, expansion

If you have a string (from a computation..) like `a1E¹+a2E²+a3E³` where `E^i=exp(i*k*τ)` is there a way to extract only the term for `E^i`?

Comment: would you mind to share a bit more of your code?

Comment: it's still a bit cryptic and I guess you mean `E^1` term.

Comment: this question doesn't make sense.  do you mean you have a bunch of data generated by a1 exp(..) + a2 exp(..) + ...?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is called `s`, and it looks like this:

```
s = 'a1 * exp(k*t) + a2 * exp(2*k*t) + a3 * exp( 3 * k * t ) + ...';
```

(I have had to extrapolate a bit... your question was rather incomplete).

you can use expression matching to find the components you're after. Notice first the `+` sign only occurs between terms; we can use the `strtok` function to split it at these points. It doesn't matter whether a1 is a number or a variable - as long as it's not an expression that includes the '+' sign. If it does... see below. If you need the nth term, you would say

```
remain = s;
for ii=1:n
  [tok remain] = strtok( remain, '+'); % split on the '+' sign, return text after in remain
end
```

At the end of this loop, `tok` contains the nth part of the expression, that is

```
an * exp( n * k * t )
```

Now, you split this at the part before `exp` by searching for that string:

```
sf = strfind( tok, 'exp' ); % returns the starting index of the string 'exp'
myFactor = tok(1:(sf(1)-1));   % returns the bit before 'exp'
```

This should be your answer... if I understood your question. If I didn't understand your question, this is complete gibberish.

Disclaimer: did not have matlab handy to run/test code; potential errors / offsets / reversed arguments, etc. Should be trivial to fix.

Addendum: if the `an` terms include `+` signs, you would have to split the string on 'exp' rather than on the `+` sign - the `strfind` function will in fact return an array of matches, so

```
sf = strfind( mystring, 'exp' );
```

would return an array of the starting points of all the 'exp' substrings. You might be able to take it from there - but as I said above, without much more detail about your string format it is hard to give a general solution...